# PHP - Why is comparison of 2 entire long (identical) strings MUCH faster than comparison of the first character of each?

Tags: php, performance

For one of my applications I assumed that comparing the first character of 2 strings would be faster than comparing the entire strings for equality. For example, if I know that only 2 possible strings (in a set of **n** strings) can start with the same letter (let's say a 'q'), and if so, they are identical strings, then I might write a comparison such as this:

```
if ($stringOne[0] === $stringTwo[0]) $qString = true;
```

instead of:

```
if ($stringOne === $stringTwo) $qString = true;
```

But I recently wrote some benchmark scripts and it seems I assumed wrong. That is, it looks to be that the 2nd comparison is 2-4 times faster on average than the second. My benchmark looked like this:

```
$x = 'A really really looooooooooooong string';
$y = 'A really really looooooooooooong string';

$timeArray = array();

//Method 1, two-four times faster than Method 2
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $t1 = microtime(true);
    for($j = 0; $j < 100000; $j++) {
        if ($x === $y) continue;
    }
    $t2 = microtime(true);
    $timeArray[] = $t2 - $t1;
}

echo array_sum($timeArray) / 100;//average time is echoed

//Method 2
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $t1 = microtime(true);
    for($j = 0; $j < 100000; $j++) {
        if ($x[0] === $y[0]) continue;
    }
    $t2 = microtime(true);
    $timeArray[] = $t2 - $t1;
}

echo array_sum($timeArray) / 100;//average time is echoed
```

I suppose I assumed that since each string $x and $y are in memory, then the first character of each is in memory too and the comparison would be faster.

Why is the whole-string comparison faster? Is there a "cost" for extracting the first character out of each string to compare them?

UPDATE: Even when new strings are generated in each outer loop iteration and compared, or the starting strings are identical or not, Method1 is still faster for me than Method2.

```
//Method 1 faster than Method 2 by 2-3 times
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $t1 = microtime(true);
    $a = $x . $i;
    $b = $y . $i;
    for($j = 0; $j < 100000; $j++) {
        if ($a === $b) continue;
    }
    $t2 = microtime(true);
    $timeArray[] = $t2 - $t1;
}

//Method 2
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $t1 = microtime(true);
    $a = $x . $i;
    $b = $y . $i;
    for($j = 0; $j < 100000; $j++) {
        if ($a[0] === $b[0]) continue;
    }
    $t2 = microtime(true);
    $timeArray[] = $t2 - $t1;
}
```

Also get the same result if comparing the two by strict inequivalence instead of strict equivalence

```
//Method 1 faster than Method 2 by 1.5-2 times, but now less of a difference
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $t1 = microtime(true);
    $a = $x . $i;
    $b = $y . $i;
    for($j = 0; $j < 100000; $j++) {
        if ($a !== $b) continue; // using inequivalence this time
    }
    $t2 = microtime(true);
    $timeArray[] = $t2 - $t1;
}

//Method 2
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $t1 = microtime(true);
    $a = $x . $i;
    $b = $y . $i;
    for($j = 0; $j < 100000; $j++) {
        if ($a[0] !== $b[0]) continue;  // using inequivalence this time
    }
    $t2 = microtime(true);
    $timeArray[] = $t2 - $t1;
}
```

Comment: What version of PHP? Are the strings hardcoded, read from file or generated dynamically?

Comment: Most likely that's due to zval references effect

Comment: for this use case only hardcoded...in my app strings are dynamically generated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Static strings, like in your script, [will be interned](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/performanceimprovements) (See [String Interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) on Wikipedia for a detailed explanation of what that means).

Essentially this means the same string will only be stored once in memory. When PHP does a comparison, it will immediately see both strings refer to the same object in memory and not need to do any further checks. Comparisons of single characters from strings very likely do not benefit from this optimization which is why they might take longer.

It is quite possible other factors also come in to play, but that will be a major one. Try constructing one or both of your strings dynamically and see how much the result changes by changing your code like so:

```
$x = base64_encode(base64_decode('A really really looooooooooooong string'));
```

---

As promised in the comments, here is a version of the script that overrides both string interning and any kind of equality cache that might be being used.

The results I get here indicate that the second method is very slightly faster.

```
<?php
$runs = 1000000;
$input_string_a = "A really really looooooooooooong string";
$input_string_b = "B really really looooooooooooong string";

$total_time = 0;
for($i=0; $i<$runs; $i++) {
    $a = substr($input_string_a, 0);
    $b = substr($input_string_b, 0);
    $start = microtime(true);
    if($a === $b) {
        if(false) break;
    }
    $end = microtime(true);
    $total_time += $end - $start;
}

echo $total_time."\n";

$total_time = 0;
for($i=0; $i<$runs; $i++) {
    $a = substr($input_string_a, 0);
    $b = substr($input_string_b, 0);
    $start = microtime(true);
    if($a[0] === $b[0]) {
        if(false) break;
    }
    $end = microtime(true);
    $total_time += $end - $start;
}

echo $total_time."\n";
```

Comment: I updated $x to be md5('original string') and $y to be 'original string' . time() and the results were essentially identical....non-equivalent strings I know but still the same result

Comment: Here are the results I got. For your original code (strings matching at compile time) `0.008, 0.026`. My modification (strings matching, not determined at compile time) `0.021 0.030`. I also got the same results for if the strings do not match (on the first character) both at compile time and at runtime.

Comment: This indicates to me that string interning is a significant factor, but there are probably other optimizations on string comparison that make it fast.

Comment: Do you also get Method1 faster than Method2 when strings are non-equivalent? Since my application has loops that can run thousands of times, a 2-3 fold time difference matters. I may need to rewrite some of the code

Comment: Yes, slightly but not by anywhere near as much. It is possible the results of direct comparisons on variables are also cached somewhere, so by doing the same comparison multiple times you end up just using a cache. I will try and write a test case that more fairly tests both methods.

Comment: I've added a script to my answer that avoids string interning and directly comparing the same memory addresses multiple times.

Comment: Which method was faster for you? Whole string or first char comparisons?

Comment: The first character comparison was faster, but not by much.